# Como fazer um dropdown ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma Classe DTO

```
[Serializable]
    public class PerfilDTO
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public SituacaoEnum Situacao { get; set; }
        public List<PerfilFuncionalidadeDTO> PerfilFuncionalidade { get; set; }

    }
```

E nessa DTO tenho o meu `SituacaoEnum` que é o abaixo:

```
 public enum SituacaoEnum
    {
        [Description("Ativo")]
        Ativo = 1,
        [Description("Inativo")]
        Inativo = 2
    }
```

Na minha view tenho o Seguinte:

```
@model IEnumerable<ControleAcesso.PerfilDTO>
```

um html qualquer e:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(this.Model.First().Situacao)
```

Como fazer um dropDown a partir do que tenho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class DropDownListHelper
    {
        public static List<SelectListItem> DropDownListEnum<T>(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> listaItens = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem itemVazio = new SelectListItem();
            itemVazio.Text = "Selecione uma opção";
            itemVazio.Value = "";
            listaItens.Add(itemVazio);

            SelectListItem itemLista;
            //int value = 1;
            //string description = Enumerations.GetEnumDescription((MyEnum)value);
            foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            {
                itemLista = new SelectListItem { Value = item.ToString(), Text = GetDescription(item) };
                listaItens.Add(itemLista);
            }

            return listaItens;
        }

        public static string GetDescription(Enum en)
        {
            Type type = en.GetType();

            MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

            if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
                return attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0 ? ((DescriptionAttribute) attrs[0]).Description : en.ToString();
            }

            return en.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**:::EDIT:::**

Encontrei uma solução Melhor!

Comment: Usando atributos anotados, não? Muito bem também. +1.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez  Permita que eu mude a reposta correta? para essa aqui? Embora todas que postaram ficaram absurdamente boas! (exceto a minha primeira rs)

Comment: Fique à vontade.

Comment: OK, vou deixar como está por hora... Muito obrigado!! essa classe ficou do carvalho! nao teria conseguido sem a ajuda de vcs!

Answer (score 4):

```
@{  var lstOpcoes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SituacaoEnum)).OfType<SituacaoEnum>().Select(sa => 
    new SelectListItem 
        {
            Text = sa.ToString(), 
            Value = ((int)sa).ToString()
        }).ToList();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(dtos => dtos.First().Situacao, lstOpcoes)
```

Comment: o que necessariamente `dtos => dtos.First().Situacao` faz? eu coloquei no meu por pedir no parametro mas não entendi o pq rs

Comment: Ele indica qual parâmetro vai ser preenchido. Neste caso, o campo `Situacao` do primeiro registro de `dtos`. Não acho essa abordagem correta, mas ela não atrapalha a resposta.

Comment: É... alguma coisa me diz que vou levar uma surra de 5 minutos de relógio parado do asp-net mvc ainda. rs. De fato funciona perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, @okevinlira

Complementando a resposta ao @Cigano, você vai reparar que com frequência será preciso repetir aquele trecho de código em que você cria uma lista de `SelectListItem`, para que as opções no `dropdownlist` sejam criadas com os valores contidos no enum.

Sugiro que faça um [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383977.aspx) para isso como mostro abaixo:

```
public static class DropDownListHelper
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> DropDownListEnum<T>(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listaItens = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem itemVazio = new SelectListItem();
        itemVazio.Text = "Selecione uma opção";
        itemVazio.Value = "";
        listaItens.Add(itemVazio);

        SelectListItem itemLista;

        foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            itemLista = new SelectListItem();

            itemLista.Value = item.ToString();
            itemLista.Text = item.Descricao();

            listaItens.Add(itemLista);
        }

        return listaItens;
    }
}
```

Depois disso o seu `DropDownListFor` deverá ser montado da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(dtos => dtos.First().Situacao, Html.DropDownListEnum<SituacaoEnum>())
```

Além de permitir que você use com qualquer outro `enum`!

Achou mais simples?

Comment: Gostei. Bem genérico. +1.

Comment: Achei sim! vou Editar a minha resposta e mostrar como eu Fiz apenas com outra extensão. Veja se Gosta também @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Usei Reflection para pegar o Attribute que fica em cima do Enum e criar o texto :)